# UITableView.reloadData() cannot get retrieve correct text

Tags: swift, uitableview

I've a `UITableView` that gets dynamic values. These values depends on user entry. User enters a string and the code gets an array from internet by using that string. In my view, `UITableView` and textField is working. When I press Get Tower(`getTowerButton()`) button, `UITableView` should reload its data with `reloadData()`. But it's not reloading, because it doesn't print 1 and 2.

**Note:** If I seperate `UITableView` and user entry to two different views code works. and table loads.

```
class AddTowerViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var ICAOCodeField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var towersTable: UITableView!
    var towersArray: Array<String> = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.ICAOCodeField.delegate = self
        
                // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    

    

    @IBAction func getTowers() {
        towersArray = getTowerNames(ICAOCode: ICAOCodeField.text!)
        self.towersTable.reloadData()
    }
    
    
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = towersTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cellos", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = towersArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return towersArray.count
    }
...
```

**EDIT:**
I've noticed that when I seperate `UITableView` and user entry view the table loads the data. I guess that the problem causes because system runs numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath methods only at first launch of belonging view.

Answer (score 2):

You're saying that getTowerNames(ICAOCode: ICAOCodeField.text!) loads data from the internet and I don't think you are doing that synchonously. I suggest you to create a completion block to handle the request's response. Like this:

```
getTowerNames(ICAOCode: ICAOCodeField.text!, completion:(names: Array<String>) -> ())
```

Then use the completion closure to reload your table.

```
getTowerNames(ICAOCode: ICAOCodeField.text!) {[weak self] names in 
    self?.towerNameArray = names
    self?.tableView.reloadData() 
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Will I return the result to completion variable?

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't load.

Comment: Set breakpoint to line with self?.towerNameArray = names and check if names are the data you need (if it isn't empty array or something). If yes, create breakpoint in cellForIndexPath method and see if it gets called after reloadData(). If not, you probably doesn't have connected tableView property with right outlet in storyboard or you forgot to set delegate and datasource

Comment: I've solved the problem roots delegate and data source protocol initialisation. Thanks