# UITableView.reloadData() is not refreshing tableView. No error message

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift4

I've already looked at the post [UITableView.reloadData() is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32794571/uitableview-reloaddata-is-not-working). I'm not sure that it applies to my situation, but let me know if I'm wrong.

My app has a tableView. From the main viewController I am opening another viewController, creating a new object, and then passing that object back to the original viewController, where it is added to an array called timers. All of that is working fine. However, when I call tableView.reloadData() in didUnwindFromNewTimerVC() to display the updated contents of the timers array, nothing happens.

NOTE: I have verified that the timers array is updated with the new object. Its count increments, and I can access its members. Everything else in didUnwindFromNewTimerVC() executes normally. The tableView just isn't updating to reflect it.

Here is my code:

```
    import UIKit
    class TimerListScreen: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tabelView: UITableView!

    var timers = [Timer]()

    let tableView = UITableView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tabelView.delegate = self
    tabelView.dataSource = self

    let tempTimer = Timer(timerLabel: "temp timer")
      timers.append(tempTimer)
    }

    @IBAction func didUnwindFromNewTimerVC(_sender:UIStoryboardSegue){
      guard let newTimerVC = _sender.source as? newTimerVC else{return}
      newTimerVC.timer.setTimerLabel(timerLabel: newTimerVC.timerLabel.text!)
      timers.append(newTimerVC.timer)
      tableView.reloadData()

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if let cell = tabelView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TimerCell", for: indexPath) as? TimerCell{

        let timer = timers[indexPath.row]

        cell.updateUI(Timer: timer)

        return cell

    }else{
        return UITableViewCell()
      }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return timers.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
       return 78
      }
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: try it in viewWillAppear ??

Comment: I tried that just in case but it works the same. The original block of code is executing, but it has no visible effect on the tableView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note the spelling. There are two table view instances: the outlet *tab**el**View* and a (pointless) instance *tab**le**View*.

Reload the data of the outlet

```
tabelView.reloadData()
```

and delete the declaration line of the second instance `let tableView ...`.

However I'd recommend to rename the outlet to correctly spelled `tableView` (you might need to reconnect the outlet in Interface Builder).

---

And force unwrap the cell

```
let cell = tabelView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TimerCell", for: indexPath) as! TimerCell
```

and remove the `if - else` part. The code must not crash if everything is hooked up correctly in IB.

Comment: Well, that was painful. Thanks for pointing that out! I stared at it for hours and didn't see it.